# Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'company_id' cannot be null laravel5.3

Tags: php, laravel-5

I  am try to set the (Table company )(Company id -> primary key) to the foreign key in (Table branch)(company_id).

Controller:

```
public function savebranchinfo(Request $request){
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
            'name' => 'required|min:5',
            'email' =>'required|unique:branch',
            'address' =>'required',
            'contact' =>'required|min:11',
            'open_hours' =>'required',
        ]);
        if($validator->passes()){
            $branch = new Branch();
            $branch->company_id = $request->company_id;
            $branch->name = $request->name;
            $branch->email = $request->email;
            $branch->address = $request->address;
            $branch->contact = $request->contact;
            $branch->open_hours = $request->open_hours;
            if($branch->save()){
                $request->session()->flash('message','Successfully save!!');
                return redirect('/add/branch');
            }
        }else{
                return redirect('/add/branch')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
        }
    }
}
```

Migration:

```
  public function up()
{
    Schema::create('branch', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('company_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('company_id')->references('id')->on('company');
        $table->String('name');
        $table->String('email');
        $table->String('address');
        $table->String('contact');
        $table->String('open_hours');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

View :

```
<input type="hidden" value="company_id{{$company->id}}">
```

Error:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'company_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `branch` (`company_id`, `name`, `email`, `address`, `contact`, `open_hours`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (, Mahmood Son, mahmoodson@gmail.com, bilal gunj, 04237152734, 8am-8pm, 2017-02-25 12:06:35, 2017-02-25 12:06:35))

Comment: company_id is auto increment column ? then remove it from list.

Comment: oh clear it shows in branch table you are trying to insert blank company id that is the issues. I Mean  ('should be some value', Mahmood Son, etc...

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you forgot the input name in the form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="company_id" value="{{$company->id}}">
```

Comment: please verify that $company->id has a value that exists in company table, just look at your html page source.